# Winjs - Windows Store App. How to display dynamic listView for each Hub section?

Tags: windows-store-apps, winjs, windows-8.1

I'm creating new project using template Hub App. The hub will have 3 sections, each section will have listView control to display items which I call from the web server. Section 1 will show Most popular items, Section 2 will show Top rated items, Section 3 will show Newest items. What is the correct way to get data from web server? Should I use WinJS.xhr 3 times to connect to server via 3 urls popular.php, toprate.php, newest.php to retrieve json data to bind it with 3 list view control?
Thanks

Comment: There's no correct way as it depends on your application and your users. The way you'd described should work, or you could combine the requests into one and then split/bind the data across the list views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hub control was designed to work with disparate data sources, that is, to host multiple ListView controls that are each drawing from different sources. Without the Hub control, people were trying to glom together disparate sources to make one source for a single ListView, then had to use templates and grouping to try to separate the pieces. As you can expect, that was messy.

So in your case, yes, use multiple http requests to get your different bits of data, build a WinJS.Binding.List (or other appropriate data source) with each one, and have each Hub section host a separate ListView.

Note also that if you don't need full ListView interactivity or variable list lengths, you can use the WinJS.UI.Repeater to simply replicate a few items from the same template using a WinJS.Binding.List as a data source.

Check the [HTML Hub Control sample in the SDK](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HTML-Hub-control-sample-a15e5c2d) for some demonstrations of hosting ListViews. I got into more detail on both the Repeater and Hub in Chapters 7 and 8 of my [second edition book preview (free from MSPress)](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2).